# Как скинуть файли на android с ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, файлы

Запускаю команду в терминале:

```
ostap@ostap-Programmer:~/Завантаження$ sudo cp slithe.apk -r /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C011%5D/Внутр.%20накопитель
```

получаю ошибку:

> cp: не удалось получить доступ к '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C011%5D/Внутр.%20накопитель': Отказано в доступе

Почему отказано в доступе?
Как тогда скинуть файлы?

Comment: вероятно, доступ имеется только у вас. копируйте от своего имени, а не от имени пользователя root.

Comment: но и графическим способом от пользователя основново(не root) тоже не копируется

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в текст вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ id; ls -ld /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C011%5D/Внутр.%20накопитель`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно примантировалось в ro моде.

Перемонтируйте в rw:

```
~# mkdir /mnt/my_abdroid
~# mount -o remount,rw /dev/your_device /mnt/my_android
```

ДЛЯ НОВИЧКОВ

Ради всех святых прочтите  хотябы описание каждой из команд прежде, чем C-c C-p

Что происходит:

Создается директоряи на ubuntu,  монтируется андроид в режиме чтения-записи в ручную.

Посмотреть имя устройства можно так:

```
~# udevadm monitor
```

отлючите-подключите, смотря вывод.

Проверте лог, узнаете процесс монтирования и что вызвало ошибку:

```
 ~# journalctl
```

или

```
 ~# less /var/log/dmsg
```

Comment: андроид точно не умрет?

Comment: ето точно безопасно?

Comment: @0stap34PHP. хороший вопрос. Если вы работаете на ubuntu и мантируете любой внеший накопитель в этом случае android устройства то все операции с ним не могут нарушить его работу. Распишу в ответе.

Comment: Если не уверены, не делайте. Если есть сомнения, прочтите описание каждой из команд. Я пока на работе muont- ом ничего не сломал ;-). И пожалуйста пишите однострочные коментарии в редактирование - это ведь не чат.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо